# Orphan <li> and </li> tags

Tags: html, regex, replace, html-lists, orphan

I inherited some html where orphan list item tags `<li> and </li>` surround certain paragraphs but without any opening nor closing `<ul> or <ol>` tags.

Is there a way to parse or find/replace in mass over 700 html files to get rid of these orphan tags?

The files also have plenty of legitimate chunks where the same tags are opened and closed normally, and those are fine, so I mustn't alter them.

I'm comfortable with RegEx, Notepad++, Excel among others  :)

Any help is much appreciated

For clarification below is a short sample file among those impacted. The orphan list is the one in the middle with line spaces before and after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="MS-HKWD" content="Commandes simplifiées:Créer une commande simplifiée" />
<meta name="topic-check-list" content="Index dynamique exécuté" />
<meta name="generator" content="Adobe RoboHelp 2019" />
<title>Purchase Module</title>
<link href="..\Model.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<p class="Local-h4">Create a basic order</p>

<hr style="color: #002c52; background-color: #002c52;" width="103.064%" align="left" />
<p class="Local-h5">How to</p>



<li><p>In left panel, click on <b>ADD</b>.<br />
&gt; An empty record is displayed.</p></li>
<li><p>Define the basic order.<br />
This mainly involves:</p></li>




<img src="../Icones/paperclip.png" alt="paperclip" border="0" /> These fields are required.</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: square;">
    <li style="text-align: left;"><p><b>Nb</b>: order number.</p></li>
    <li style="text-align: left;"><p><b>Status</b>*: current status of the order.</p></li>
    <li style="text-align: left;"><p><b>Destination</b>: department requesting the goods.</p></li>
    <li style="text-align: left;"><p><b>Supplier*</b>: 4 digit supplier code.
    </p>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're comfortable with regex I guess you've tried removing the orphans using regex? If so, what did you try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TedLyngmo 
Hi Ted. Mainly I did searching with RegEx like <li>((?s:.*?))</li> to find the child elements. But that does not help obviously to tell which have parent tag and which don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DOM parser and then find the orphaned `li` elements and remove them, using the DOM API. Finally extract the resulting HTML:

```js
function removeOrphanListItems(html) {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    doc.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li =>
        !["UL","OL"].includes(li.parentNode.tagName) && li.remove()
    )
    return doc.body.innerHTML;
}

let html = "<ul><li>one<li>two</ul><div><li>three</li></div>";
console.log(removeOrphanListItems(html));
```

### After edit to your question...

It became clear that your HTML is actually the content of your HTML page on which the script runs. In that case, you can apply the above logic directly on the DOM of that page:

```js
function removeOrphanListItems() {
    document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li =>
        !["UL","OL"].includes(li.parentNode.tagName) && li.remove()
    )
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", removeOrphanListItems);
```

```html
<p class="Local-h4">Create a basic order</p>

<hr style="color: #002c52; background-color: #002c52;" width="103.064%" align="left" />
<p class="Local-h5">How to</p>

<li><p>In left panel, click on <b>ADD</b>.<br />
&gt; An empty record is displayed.</p></li>
<li><p>Define the basic order.<br />
This mainly involves:</p></li>

<img src="../Icones/paperclip.png" alt="paperclip" border="0" /> These fields are required.</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: square;">
    <li style="text-align: left;"><p><b>Nb</b>: order number.</p></li>
    <li style="text-align: left;"><p><b>Status</b>*: current status of the order.</p></li>
    <li style="text-align: left;"><p><b>Destination</b>: department requesting the goods.</p></li>
    <li style="text-align: left;"><p><b>Supplier*</b>: 4 digit supplier code.
    </p>
</ul>
```

Comment: Trincot, thank you very much sounds really promising. I have to admit though that I've never used a DOM parser. I'll ask a colleague for help :)

Comment: @AymanAlhaj, you will want to repost that latter comment in the comment section below your question instead of here, and add the @ symbol before the username you want to ping.

Comment: If there is something that is not clear in my answer, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for all the tips, will do  :)
Matter of fact, I have no idea where to place the function you kindly provided.

Comment: I hadn't noticed you had edited the question after I posted my answer. Now it becomes clear your reference to HTML is actually referring to the current document when running in a browser context. See addition to answer.

Comment: It worked great! Thank you again.
I just had to adjust the function a bit to remove only the tag effect/attribute but not the text between the tags, so I ended up using removeAttribute instead of remove. All set!  :)
function removeOrphanListItems() {
    document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li =>
        !["UL","OL"].includes(li.parentNode.tagName) && li.removeAttribute("li")
    )
}